# are phonegap img and css files stored within app or on the cloud?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

i'm wondering if I should load all images for a phonegap app from my web server or if there is any benefit to using the phonegap img folder to store some images like icons? If phonegap stores them on its cloud then i may as well load all files on my webserver? If packaged inside the app then it makes sense to store static files in the phonegap img folder. Thanks heaps!

Comment: http://phonegap.com/about/faq/

Comment: thanks but i'm still unsure if the images stored on the phonegap build cloud as faq suggests, or are they packaged inside an app and stored locally on the android device? so by pasting the link you're trying to say it's all on the cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@xmxmxmx
Okay I see the confusion. The ["Creative Cloud"](http://www.adobe.com/creativecloud.html) (by Adobe) is not required by Phonegap. It is an additional package by Adobe. Sort of like - Google Cloud service, AWS, or any of a dozen cloud services. To be clear, there is no network (or Internet) service required to use phonegap.

On your original question, "Best Practice" is - where practical - store on the device all assets. This includes, but is not limited to:

- images, icon, splashscreens
- javascript libraries
- css, fonts, and related

In addition, *Cordova/Phonegap* is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005). It is also worth knowing that Google and Apple frowns on using apps as wrappers for websites.

*Quote* ***[Google Developer Program Policies](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) - Spam and Placement in the Store***

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
>      - Drive affiliate traffic to a website or
>      - Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so)

*Quote* ***[Apple iTunes Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) - 2.12***

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Here are some helpful links:

**FAQ**

- [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md) - **READ THIS FIRST** Read just the **bold** sentences, then come back to it later.
- [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/), see the middle for "Corodva tools". These are companies that do the same as Cordova or with Cordova.

**support groups**

- [Google Group of Cordova/Phonegap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap)
- [Nitobi forum for Phonegap Build](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi)

**Boilerplates**

- *Phonegap* [Hello World Tutorial](http://docs.phonegap.com/develop/hello-world-explained/)
- [An HTML Boilerplate for Phonegap](http://codesnippets.altervista.org/blog/2015/BLOG.2015-06-10.jssnippets.html)